# csh/sh for loop - how to?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, csh

i'm trying to write a for loop that executes 2 scripts on FreeBSD. I don't care if it's written in sh or csh. I want something like:

```
for($i=11; $i<=24; $i++)
{
   exec(tar xzf 'myfile-1.0.' . $i);
   // detect an error was returned by the script
   if ('./patch.sh')
   {
      echo "Patching to $i failed\n";
   }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this please?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using csh for scripting - that is NOT what it was intended for. Use bash, ksh or even sh instead.

Comment: no choice. it's the only shell on freebsd i can use. unless i can use sh, in which case i'm looking for an sh solution.

Comment: @Neil - who knows? If it has, an sh script would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

csh does loops fine, the problem is that you are using exec, which replaces the current program (which is the shell) with a different one, *in the same process*.  Since others have supplied sh versions, here is a csh one:

```
    #!/bin/csh
    set i = 11
    while ($i < 25)
        tar xzf "myfile-1.0.$i"

        # detect an error was returned by the script   
        if ({./patch.sh}) then     
            echo "Patching to $i failed"   
        endif
        @ i = $i + 1
    end
```

Not sure about the `./patch.sh` are you testing for its existence or running it? I am running it here, and testing the result - true means it returned zero.  Alternatively:

```
        # detect an error was returned by the script   
        if (!{tar xzf "myfile-1.0.$i"}) then     
            echo "Patching to $i failed"   
        endif
```

Comment: Yes, I agree, but that does not help the OP.

Comment: I suggest `#!/bin/csh -f`. The `-f` tells the shell not to source your startup files, `.cshrc` and `.login`, which makes the script run faster and avoids dependencies. (This applies only to csh/tcsh; sh and bash have a `-f` option, but it's entirely different.)

Answer (score 7):

The typical way to do this in sh is:

```
for i in $(seq 11 24); do 
   tar xzf "myfile-1.0$i" || exit 1
done
```

Note that `seq` is not standard.  Depending on the availability of tools, you might try:

```
jot 14 11 24
```

or

```
perl -E 'say for(11..24)'
```

or

```
yes '' | nl -ba | sed -n -e 11,24p -e 24q
```

I've made a few changes: I abort if the tar fails and do not emit an error message, since tar should emit the error message instead of the script.

Comment: freebsd includes a tool 'jot' that is something like seq

Answer (score 5):

Wow! No BASH. And probably no Kornshell:

```
i=11
while [ $i -le 24 ]
do
    tar xzf myfile-1.0.$i
    i=`expr $i + 1`
    if ./patch.sh
    then
        echo "patching to $i failed"
    fi
done
```

Written in pure Bourne shell just like God intended.

Note you have to use the `expr` command to add 1 to `$i`. Bourne shell doesn't do math. The backticks mean to execute the command and put the STDOUT from the command into `$i`.

Kornshell and BASH make this much easier since they can do math and do more complex for loops.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should just use bash. I don't have it here, so it cannot test it, but something along this should work:

```
for ((I=11; I<=24; I++)) ; do
   tar xzf myfile-1.0.$I || echo Patching to $I failed
done
```

EDIT: Just read the comments and found out there's no bash in FreeBSD default installation. So this might not work at all - I'm not sure about the differences between (t)csh and bash.

Comment: I think noone should use bashisms when an equivalent POSIX shell solution is easily written. "All the world's a bash" strikes me as the 3rd millennium version of "All the world's a VAX".

Answer (score -1):

Well what i just did is the following.

> sh

Load sh shell and then for loop works like on linux.

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/yourfilename$i.test bs=52428800 count=15; done
```